# How to use scipy.optimize with array function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I created a custom-made exponential smoothing function. I want to optimize its parameters thanks to scipy.optimize.basinhopping.

If I only optimize the function for one time serie **it works**.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
d = [1,2,3,4]   
cols = len(d) 
def simple_exp_smooth(inputs):
    ini,alpha = inputs
    f = np.full(cols,np.nan) 
    f[0] = ini
    for t in range(1,cols):
        f[t] = alpha*d[t-1]+(1-alpha)*f[t-1]           
    error = sum(abs(f[1:] - d[1:]))
    return error
func = simple_exp_smooth
bounds = np.array([(0,4),(0.0, 1.0)])
x0 = (1,0.1)
res = basinhopping(func, x0, minimizer_kwargs={'bounds': bounds},stepsize=0.1,niter=45)
```

One of the issue of this is that it is slow if you have 1000 time series to optimize. So I have created an array version to perform the exponential smoothing of multiple time series at once.

```
def simple(inputs):
    a0,alpha  = inputs
    a = np.full([rows,cols],np.nan)
    a[:,0] = a0
    for t in range(1,cols):
        a[:,t] = alpha*d[:,t]+(1-alpha)*a[:,t-1]
    MAE = abs(d - a).mean(axis=1)/d.mean(axis=1)
    return sum(MAE)

d = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [10,20,30,40]])
rows, cols = d.shape

a0_bound = np.vstack((d.min(axis=1),d.max(axis=1))).T
a0_ini = d.mean(axis=1)
bounds = ([a0_bound,(0.0, 1.0)])
x0 = (a0_ini,0.2)
res = basinhopping(simple, x0, minimizer_kwargs={'bounds': bounds},stepsize=0.1)
```

But now, the basinhopping gives me this error:

```
bounds = [(None if l == -np.inf else l, None if u == np.inf else u) for l, u in bounds]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there any way for me to use basinhopping to optimize my whole array at once instead of each line one by one?

Comment: From the `basinhopping` docs: `Basin-hopping is a stochastic algorithm which attempts to find the global minimum of a smooth scalar function of one or more variables`.  See that **scalar function** phrase?

Comment: Have you thought through the implications of trying to optimize all series at once, with a smoothing function that works on all (at once)?  Do really want a different solution (and solution method), or are you just focused on speed?

Comment: for me the main objective is speed. Going through a 1000 rows takes too long, and I know that if I compute the function with arrays it is much faster. Is there any way to use this array function? I need different parameters for each row, so there is no interest into getting one parameter for all of them at once.

Comment: The function is scalar, I can return sum(MAE) which is then a scalar.

Comment: The big speed jumps in `numpy` come when you move Python level iterations into compiled code.  But that only works for basic operations like operators and `ufuncs`.  `basinhopping` is  a complex operation written largely in Python, and calling your `simple` for each trial `inputs`.

Comment: Have you tried to make the optimization for one Series faster?  Either by reducing the number of calls to the smoother, or speeding up the smoother.  How many times, typically, is the smoother called per optimization?  Can you 'vectorize' the smoother?  I see a `for` loop.

Comment: I have created my own version of this. It can brute-force optimize 1000 rows in 10 seconds. Here to optimize one row is 1.7 seconds. So the only way to use this basinhopping efficiently is to use it at once on the whole dataset.